# How to optimize a MySQL query so that a selected value in a WHERE clause is only computed once?

Tags: mysql

I need to randomly select, in an efficient way, 10 rows from my table.

I found out that the following works nicely (after the query, I just select 10 random elements in PHP from the 10 to 30 I get from the query):

```
   SELECT * FROM product WHERE RAND() <= (SELECT 20 / COUNT(*) FROM product)
```

However, the subquery, though relatively cheap, is computed for every row in the table. How can I prevent that? With a variable? A join?

Thanks!

Comment: why not this? "select * from YOUR_TABLE order by rand() limit 10"

Comment: @Cristian-Boariu This is NOT efficient at all on large tables (it has to be sorted entirely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a highly mysql specific trick but by wrapping it in another subquery MySQL will make it a constant table and compute it only once.

```
 SELECT * FROM product WHERE RAND() <= (
  select * from ( SELECT 20 / COUNT(*) FROM product ) as const_table
 )
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.0, it does not work :

`#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: (Though I like the fact that it's simple -- though it's ugly ;) -- and a single query)

Comment: The error 1248 is a typo on my part - just  a mis-placement of parenthesis. Can you retry?

Comment: It does work. Sorry I missed the parenthesis typo.

The `COUNT(*)` is still pretty long (50 ms to count my 10,000 rows? Come on!), but that will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A variable would do it. Something like this:

```
SELECT @myvar := (SELECT 20 / COUNT(*) FROM product);
SELECT * FROM product WHERE RAND() <= @myvar;
```

Or, from the [MySql math functions doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html):

> You cannot use a column with RAND()
>   values in an ORDER BY clause, because
>   ORDER BY would evaluate the column
>   multiple times. However, you can
>   retrieve rows in random order like
>   this:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY
> RAND();
```

> ORDER BY RAND() combined with LIMIT is
>   useful for selecting a random sample
>   from a set of rows:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table1, table2
> WHERE a=b AND c<d -> ORDER BY RAND()
> LIMIT 1000;
```

> RAND() is not meant to be a perfect
>   random generator. It is a fast way to
>   generate random numbers on demand that
>   is portable between platforms for the
>   same MySQL version.

Comment: I cannot use `ORDER BY RAND()`, because it's too inefficient on a large table. I like your first proposition, but can I do that in just one query?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to run that first code snippet (using a variable) as a single statement w/o problems. Just don't forget the ; (semicolon) statement separator.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This is not efficient enough on large tables

Answer (score 0):

Don't use order by rand().  This will result in a table scan.  If you have much data at all in your table this will not be efficient at all. First determine how many rows are in the table:

`select count(*) from table` might work for you, though you should probably cache this value for some time since it can be slow for large datasets.

`explain select * from table` will give you the db statistics for the table (how many rows the statistics thinks are in the table)  This is much faster, however it is less accurate and less accurate still for InnoDB.

once you have the number of rows, you should write some code like:

pseudo code:

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN (";
for (int i=0;i<numResults;i++) {
SQL += (int)(Math.rand() * tableRows) + ", ";
}
// trim off last ","
SQL.trim(",");
SQL += ")";
```

this will give you fast lookup on PK and avoid the table scan.

Comment: I know I can't use `ORDER BY RAND()`. I can't use your solution either because my ids are not contiguous (they're not even numerical...)

Comment: A numerical PK is going to perform better.  But even if you have CHAR PK type, you can still use this method, just don't use int.  There is no requirement that they be contiguous.  Consider: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE id IN ('abc123', 'pkr982', 'zfw012')`.  You may have trouble creating the ids if they are not numerical.  Consider adding an auto_increment integer PK ?